# How to execute user defined javascript code using spidermonkey

Tags: c++, spidermonkey

I have the following javascript code as string

std::string script = " { function execute() { var x=10; return x; } } ";

I want to evaluate this script and return the value , is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate a JS script you will need

```
JSBool JS_EvaluateScript(JSContext *cx, JSObject *obj, const char *src, uintN length, const char *filename, uintN lineno, jsval *rval);
```

As described here : [JS_EvaluateScript - SpiderMonkey | MDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20130823180055/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_EvaluateScript)

Then if you want to get the returned value you have to call the exectue function :

```
"function execute(){ var x = 10; return x;} execute();"
```

Then to evaluate the script have to be a `const char*` type not a `std::string`

After evaluating the script you can get the returned value using rval

```
if(JSVAL_IS_INT(rval))
  printf("The returned value is : %d\n", JSVAL_TO_INT(rval));
```